# Getting data on area where shapefile overlaps raster file using QGIS?

Tags: raster, vector, qgis-3, zonal-statistics

[image: Two layers I wish to get data on]

I have attached an image to help explain what I am asking. I want to get the average value of where the heat map crosses over each municipality in the shapefile and export those values into a spreadsheet. The heatmap is a raster image. I use QGIS 3.0.

Comment: I edited my original question to show that I am using QGIS 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "[Raster zonal statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#raster-zonal-statistics)" algorithm (tool) in - *Processing toolbox > Raster analysis > Zonal statistics*

> **Raster zonal statistics**
>
> Calculates statistics of a raster layer for each feature of an
>   overlapping polygon vector layer.
>
> *Warning* no new output file will be created. The algorithm adds new columns to the source vector layer
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - Raster layer [raster]
> - Band number [raster band] Default: Band 1 (Gray)
> - Vector layer containing zones [vector: polygon]
> - Output column prefix [string] Default: _
> - Statistics to calculate

[image]